# ngx-sipper-wrapper is not working properly in angular8?

Tags: angular, typescript, slider

I have `angular8` app in which i have a `slider component(child component)` in which i have html is like this

```
<div class="main-slider">
<div class="swiper-container h-100" [swiper]="config">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper h-100">
        <div *ngFor="let slide of arraySlides" class="swiper-slide">

            <div [attr.data-background]="slide.image" class="slide-item swiper-lazy">
                <div class="container sl-wrap">
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>

                    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center left" class="content">
                        <h1>{{slide.title}}</h1>
                        <h3>{{slide.subtitle}}</h3>
                        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Shop now</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination white"></div>
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="swiper-button-prev swipe-arrow"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon></button>
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="swiper-button-next swipe-arrow"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my `slider.component.ts` i have following

```
 public slides = [
  {
    image: 'http://localhost:5000/uploads/banner/toaster-oven-00.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Up to 70%',
    title: 'Huge Discount'
  },
  {
    image: 'http://localhost:5000/uploads/banner/tv-01.png',
    subtitle: 'Special selection',
    title: 'OUR BEST PRODUCTS'
  },
  {
    image: 'http://localhost:5000/uploads/banner/washing-00.png',
    subtitle: 'Only for today',
    title: 'MASSIVE SALE'
  }
];
```

parent `component(home.component.html)`

```
<div class="carousel-2-wrapper" fxLayout.sm="column" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="75" fxFlex.md="60" fxFlex.sm="100">
  <app-main-carousel [slides]="slides"></app-main-carousel>
</div>
```

Problem is that on the initial load of the page slider's first image is not loading and then when slider slides to the next slide so then image starts showing in the slider. I don't know what's the issue here. Here is the video of the issue https://streamable.com/49kcfd

Comment: did you initialize slides data in ngOnInit?

Comment: No i initialize `slides` array in the start of class. Not in `ngOnInit`

Comment: try in ngOnInIt